# Breaking a contour integral into 3 separate contours?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

We can try to integrate the following function around a counter-clockwise circular contour:

$$\frac{x^3}{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}$$

Can someone show how to use the Cauchy–Goursat theorem (explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-Goursat_theorem)) to break this apart into 3 separate contours?

In other words, I'd like to take

$$\int_c{\frac{x^3}{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}}$$

and get

$$\int_{C_1}{f_1(x)} + \int_{C_2}{f_2(x)} + \int_{C_3}{f_3(x)}$$

I'm hoping for a pretty thorough explanation with at least one of the contours.  I just want to be certain I have the idea perfected.

Comment: If $C_1$ encircles only the $(x=1)$-pole, and $f_1(x) = \frac{x^3}{(x-2)(x-3)}$, what does Cauchy's integral formula say about the value of $f_1(1)$?

Comment: @Arthur: I believe $f_1(1)$ is equal to $\frac{1}{2 \pi i}$ $\int_{C_1} \frac{f_1(z)}{z - 1}$

Comment: And if you write out the integrand, what do you have?

Comment: @Arthur: You have the original function.  So it seems to me that we have a choice of integrating over the original function or integrating around the poles, with some algebra.  Also, I guess we could skip integrating altogether using the result that Christopher A. Wong shows below.  This is interesting - thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Well, I wasn't going to suggest actually integrating anything. My comments more or less duplicate mr. Wong's approach, only I have yet to mention the integral theorem, which stitches together the integrals around each pole to a single integral around all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to break apart the contour into three parts so that each part contains exactly one pole, take a look at the [Mercedes-Benz symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercedes-Benz). Imagine the circle is the original contour. Your function $f(z)$ has three poles, so we subdivide the circle into three parts so that each part corresponds to one of the contours, each of which contains exactly one pole.

So now we have our $C_1, C_2, C_3$ contours. So then we can break up our original integral into
$$ \int_{C_1} f(z) \, dz + \int_{C_2} f(z) \, dz + \int_{C_3} f(z) \, dz$$
So the integrand isn't actually different. However, because each contour contains only one pole, we can take advantage of the integral formula as follows: suppose we are looking at the $C_1$ contour; then $z = 1$ is the only pole, so then we should write
$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{z - 1} \left( \frac{ x^3}{(x - 2)(x - 3)} \right) = \frac{f_1(z)}{z - 1}$$
then
$$ \int_{C_1} f(z) \, dz = \int_{C_1} \frac{f_1(z)}{z - 1} \, dz = 2\pi i f_1(1) $$
according to the integral formula. We repeat this same process similarly for the other contours.

Comment: I think I understand that there will be three poles, but I'm still wondering, when I look at the Wikipedia example at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula, how exactly the formulas get rearranged when integrating about the poles.  I don't know how to get the formulas for the integrals about the poles.

Comment: @MattGroff, I have expanded on my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  That helps a lot!

Comment: What theorem is responsible for that the integral around the original contour is equal to the sum of the contour integrals around the poles?